# Accessing second element from a div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following code snippet

```
<div class='container'>
                <a href=''>
                    <img alt='' class='image0' src='images/Gallery/gallery-01.jpg' title='info'/>
                </a>
                <a href=''>
                    <img alt='' class='image1' src='images/Gallery/gallery-01.jpg' title='info'/>
                </a>
                <a href=''>
                    <img alt='' class='image2' src='images/Gallery/gallery-01.jpg' title='info'/>
                </a>
            </div>
```

I could use

`$('.container a:first')` or `$('.container a:last')` to access the first and the last elements, but how can i access the second anchor tag on the div? .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [`:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector:

```
$('.container a:eq(1)')
```

or (preferably) the [`.eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) function:

```
$('container a').eq(1)
```

Comment: +1 for using the `eq` function; it's by far the quicker method, as `querySelectorAll` doesn't support the `eq` selector.

Comment: tried adding a dot to the second class but stackoverflow doesnt allow it.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
$( '.container > a:eq(1)' )
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/rK4qc/

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('.container a:nth-child(2)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try $('.container a:first').next(); to get the second element.

Answer (score 0):

`$('.container a')[1]` will return the DOM element.

`$($('.container a')[1])` will get you a Jquery object for the second object.

Check your result lengths appropriately.